# 一定時間敵からの攻撃を無効化したい

Tags: c#, unity3d, game-development

キーボードのGキーを押したら5秒間敵からの攻撃を無効化させる方法を教えてください。

「Unity 攻撃　一定時間　無効化」などでGoogle検索をかけ、Colliderを無効化するという方法でCancelInvokeとTime.deltaTimeを使って試したところ、攻撃は無効化されましたが、攻撃が無効化された状態から戻らなくなってしまいました。よろしければ解決策を教えてください。

```
private float countup = 0.0f;
public float timeLimit = 5.0f;
void Muteki()
{
    Debug.Log("muteki");
    CapCol.enabled = false;
    
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G))
    {
        Invoke("Muteki", 0.1f);
        countup += Time.deltaTime;
    }
  
    if (countup >= timeLimit)
    {
        CancelInvoke();
        Debug.Log("mutekiowari");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

3点問題があると思います。

- CapCol.enabledをtrueに戻す処理がない
- countupがtimeLimitを超えても0にリセットされない
- CancelInvokeの使い方が違っている
  CancelInvokeはInvokeを実行するまで(この場合0.1秒まで)に
  指定した関数の実行をキャンセルするときに使います。

最後のifブロックを以下のように変えてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
if (countup >= timeLimit)
{
    //以下2行を追記
    CapCol.enabled = true;
    countup = 0.0f;

    Debug.Log("mutekiowari");
}
```